# Starting Python Program with Screen Automatically

Tags: boot, python, screen

I'm trying to turn a headless Pi into a single purpose computer. The application I wrote uses a ncurses GUI and I want it to start on boot. The program also needs to be run on a separate 'screen' (same physical screen, seperate window) using the 'screen' application. The reason being so I can view the output of the same application on two separate screens.

I've used various renditions of /etc/init.d/example.sh, but nothing seems to work properly. The program starts, but not in a new screen. Instead, the terminal screen shows the last part of the boot sequence chopped up. If I exit the screen session, the Python application appears, but is buggy.

Here is an example of the shell script:

> ```
> start)
> echo "Starting LAM!"
> screen -S test -X test python /home/pi/cur.py
> ;;
> ```

Almost everything above and below this is commented out and in the 'skeleton'. I've been trying to make this work for 3+ hours with no success. If someone could help me it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lenik, thank you for your reply, but I ended up discovering the answer. I needed the screen to display the program and remain on it after login (sorry for not mentioning).

What I did:

First, I auto logged in by altering a line in the /etc/inittab script file from:

> 1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty --noclear 38400 tty1

to:

> 1:2345:respawn:/sbin/mingetty --autologin pi --noclear tty1

make sure to apt-get 'mingetty':

> sudo apt-get install mingetty

Then after rebooting, the Pi automatically logged the user 'pi' in. After this I went to:

> cd /home/pi/.profile

and added to the end of the script the line:

> screen python /home/pi/cur.py

but I needed the program to restart if it crashed, so I put the previous command in a infinte loop as follows:

> for (( ; ; ))
>
> do
>
> -- sudo screen python /home/pi/cur.py
>
> done

After all this I restarted the Pi and it worked as I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

`screen` programs do not really work well with `init.d/` start/stop/restart logic, you may have more success trying to start your program from `/etc/rc.local`, just don't forget to make it an executable file.

Answer (score 0):

### Persistent/Flexible screen

`xterm  -name XTerm -title PICKANAME -geometry 200x20 -e 'screen -dURS PICKANAME -X python /path/to/script.py`

The above command will open an xterm window of a specific size and title and open the screen session.  If such a session does not exist, it will be created.  If the session is opened elsewhere, the screen will be detached and re-attached to the newly created XTerm.

### Startup

If you want for the screen to be available at startup, you can add it to your *Startup Applications* or you can add it to **/etc/rc.local**.  If you add it to your rc.local file, be sure to detach the process.

`screen -dURS PICKANAME -X python /path/to/script.py &`

or

`screen -dURS PICKANAME -X python /path/to/script.py && disown`