# Opening python script in screen on boot

Tags: boot, pi-zero-w

I'm getting very annoyed here right now. I've been trying to get something very easy done for way too long now.

I am running a python script on my Pi Zero W (in CLI) to control my smart lights, this means, of course, that the script is using network access right off the bat. I want to be able to control and monitor this script directly on the pi (via keyboard and monitor) and via an external pc via ssh. I've made this work using `screen`. Now I want the Pi to automatically create the screen socket and execute the python script.

To do this manually I'm *successfully* using the following command:

```
screen -S startup /home/pi/launcher
```

I'm using the name startup to connect to the correct screen on the separate pc.

`/home/pi/launcher` is a separate file that simply calls the python script.

I can't find any way to execute this single line of code automatically in such a way that things work. I think I've tried every method on Google, none with any success.

Comment: Have you seen [Starting Python Program with Screen Automatically](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8036/starting-python-program-with-screen-automatically?rq=1)? Does that help?

Comment: Yeeeeeeees! Thanks, Aurora! This works like I intended it to work. Weird I hadn't found this method myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Aurora0001 I was able to make it work using `/etc/profile`. This is a file that runs everytime a user is logged in. I added the following code to the end of that file:

```
NAME="startup"
LIST="$(screen -list | grep $NAME)"

if [ -z "${LIST}" ]
then
screen -S $NAME /home/pi/launcher
else
screen -x $NAME
fi
```

First I get a `LIST` of all active `screen` elements using `screen -list`. Then I use `grep` to remove everything from that list except lines containing the screen `NAME` I need.

If the script doesn't find an active screen with the desired `NAME` in `LIST` then I start a `screen` with that name running `home/pi/launcher` inside it using `screen -S $NAME /home/pi/launcher`

If the script does find an active screen with the desired `NAME` in `LIST` then I'll enter it in multiscreen mode using `screen -x $NAME`